# reading content of blob from azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-function-async

I'm trying to read the content of a blob inside an azure function.

Here's the code:

Note: 
If I comment out the using block and return the blob i.e.

return new OkObjectResult(blob);

I get back the blob object.

However, if I use the using block, I get 500.

Any idea why I can't get the content?

```
string storageConnectionString = "myConnectionString";
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConnectionString, out storageAccount);
CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("drawcontainer");


var blob = drawingsContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("notes.txt");

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(blob.OpenRead()))
{
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
return new OkObjectResult(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 500 indicates that the code has error. The most probable reason for error is the variable '**content**'. Define the variable '**content**' outside the using block as the scope of the `content` variable defined inside it is limited to the block only. Declare it outside the using block, something like below:

```
    try
    {
        string content = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(blob.OpenRead()))
        {
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log exception to get the details.    
    }
```

Always make use of try catch to get more details about errors in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the variable content is not the issue (even though its declaration was missing). I placed try catch but didn't get a descriptive error

Comment: I placed some logs and I think the issue is the blob.OpenRead() - I think the OpenRead might not exists on the blob but I still didn't resolve the issue

Comment: The error that keep repeating is:
error CS0103: The name 'CloudStorageAccount' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Avi Would you please provide the nuget package and the framework details? Also, please add/edit the complete code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenRead method didn't exist so I used the async one and it solved it.

I got to this solution after creating an azure function in VS and publishing it and it works.

Here's the code I used:

```
 public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<ActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        string storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=avitest19a1c;AccountKey=<AccessKey>";
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;
        CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConnectionString, out storageAccount);
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer drawingsContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("drawcontainer");

        var blob = drawingsContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("notes.txt");

        string content = string.Empty;
        **var contentStream = await blob.OpenReadAsync();**
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(contentStream))
        {
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return new OkObjectResult(content);

    }
}
```